# Java IO file length() and lastModified() perform slow with million of files

Tags: java, io

I have 1 millions of file on remote server. these files updated frequently. where we download those file at local server at some particular time after checking. this download done basis on change in file size and modified time between remote and local server files.

1. This checking(using length() and lastModified()) makes lots of IO calls at local server and need to use both length and lastModified() this is some scenario.
2. Please note : Remote server is FTP server and I can not have control
   over it. I have 100-200 remote FTP server to get the data . for each
   FTP server there is a thread.

   please suggest efficient solution where I can reduce the IO calls for local  files, with remote server there is no issue.

   Thanks .

Comment: you could just check modification time and not the size; but I'm not sure it's not the same `lstat` call. At any rate, perform the check on the local machine, not through networked filesystem!

Comment: Check whether sync is available, but if you have no better access...

Comment: Please explain or share link about sync . Could not understand.

Answer (score 2):

Network calls are expensive. I suggest you to create a server that will receive date and return list of files that modified after that date and run it on your remote machine. Then download only files that you want.

If remote host is linux server you can just run `find` with appropriate parameters to get your list of changed files. In this case consult with `unix.stackexchange.com`.

Comment: Remote server is FTP server and I donot have control over it.

Comment: If it is only accesible via FTP there is nothing you can do.

Comment: is using NIO api  beneficial here ?

Comment: Don't think so. But I have idea. Maybe you can open several ftp session and do the job in parallel?

Comment: @user0011 - No issue, you can manage threads using ExecutorService to get the job done!

Comment: @user0011 even use 10 thread instead of 1 can lead to huge performance inprovment. As long as you have no other option I suggest you to try to use multiple threads.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention scenario that I have heavy IO calls at local server not at the remote server. updated the question as well.

Comment: this is complitely different question

Comment: yes agree but I missed this condition..sorry for confusion.